# Python code to automatically assign parsed json objects to their original names

Tags: python, json

I have dumped a couple of variables I need to store in a json object as shown here-

```
def write_json():
    variable = {}
    variable['p_id'] = p_id
    variable['s_id'] = s_id
    variable['t_id'] = t_id
    variable['b_start'] = b_start
    variable['b_end'] = b_end
    variable['wsp_after'] = wsp_after
    variable['h_id'] = h_id
    variable['word'] = word
    variable['norm_word'] = norm_word
    variable['lemma'] = lemma
    variable['pos'] = pos
    variable['ner'] = ner
    variable['dep'] = dep
    variable['quote'] = quote
    variable['ch_id'] = ch_id

    with open('variable.json', 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(variable,fp, sort_keys = True)
```

I want to write a piece of code that would automatically get these variables assigned appropriately as would happen if you wrote from 'X.py' import *

This is what I tried-

```
def get_variables():
    with open('variable.json', 'r') as fp:
        variable = json.load(fp)
    for key in variable:
        global key
        key = variable[key]
```

However, when I tried to print the original value-

```
    print t_id
NameError: name 't_id' is not defined
```

What do I need to do to achieve what I want rather than cumbersomely typing

```
t_id = variable['t_id']
.
.
.
```

For every variable I have dumped?

Comment: I tried this same code outside a function as well, with no results

Comment: variable = dict(line.split(",") for line in open('variable.json', 'r'))

Comment: Now that this question has been reopened, please add your solution as an answer (rather than as an addendum to the question).

Answer (score 0):

Your current code doesn't work because the following lines just bind (and rebind, for the later values in the loop) a global variable named `'key'`:

```
global key
key = variable[key]
```

While I'm not sure your design is really a good one, if you're sure you want all the values from your json file as global variables, I'd replace the loop with:

```
globals().update(variable)
```

The `globals()` function returns a dictionary that contains all the current module's global variables. Unlike the dictionary you get from `locals()` (which may be a copy of the local namespace, not the actual implementation of it), you can modify the `globals()` dictionary and use the variables like normal afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution -

```
with open('variable.json', 'r') as fp:
    variable = json.load(fp)

for key in  variable.keys():
    exec(key + " = variable['" + key + "']")
```

The problem before was that each 'key' was a string, not an object.
Using the exec function successfully parses each string into an object and using it as given above gets the results as was asked in the question.